# How do I specify where the dsc, build, changes, update, tar.gz files go when running debuild?

Tags: build, debian, packaging

Once in a while I like to send a version of my software to my Ubuntu PPA on Launchpad. To do so, I need to regenerate the *source, description, and change* files. To do that, I run the following command:

```
debuild -S -sa -nc -m"alexis@example.com"
```

The problem is that it spits out all the files one directory up from my main folder. So say I am working on a project named Beautiful, I would see:

```
projects/
projects/Beautiful/
projects/Beautiful/<source files from my git>
projects/Beautiful_1.2.3~xenial.dsc
projects/Beautiful_1.2.3~xenial_source.build
projects/Beautiful_1.2.3~xenial_source.changes
projects/Beautiful_1.2.3~xenial_source.ppa.upload
projects/Beautiful_1.2.3~xenial.tar.gz
```

I would like to place all of the *source* files in a sub-folder such as:

```
projects/
projects/Beautiful/
projects/Beautiful/<source files from my git>
projects/Beautiful_source/Beautiful_1.2.3~xenial.dsc
projects/Beautiful_source/Beautiful_1.2.3~xenial_source.build
projects/Beautiful_source/Beautiful_1.2.3~xenial_source.changes
projects/Beautiful_source/Beautiful_1.2.3~xenial_source.ppa.upload
projects/Beautiful_source/Beautiful_1.2.3~xenial.tar.gz
```

Is it possible from the command line or a rule somewhere? Or is the one directory up the only place where `debuild` will work on that?